# How can I change the word "comment" in a Squarespace6 blog using CSS?

Tags: css, comments, blogs, squarespace

I need to change the word "comment" to "Sign the Guestbook" on my Squarespace blog.  The support team said I could do this through CSS but they couldn't offer any further help with this "advanced modification."  All help is appreciated.  Thanks a lot guys.
-Dan

Comment: Post the HTML and CSS of your blog and we might be able to help you

Comment: Okay thank you, I'm using a SS template and don't have a developer account, which is my main problem I think.  But here is the link to the blog itself: https://daniel-nesfeder-yjen.squarespace.com/obituaries

Comment: You can see the reason I need to change the wording is because a "comment" wouldn't be respectful for an obituary, which is my use for the blog feature.

Comment: @danesfeder `Squarespace trial accounts are not visible to the public`

Comment: FWIW I don't consider "Comment" disrespectful, even for an obituary. Not nearly as bad as people "liking" posts on Facebook about people passing away, and that is done all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a nice way to do this with CSS, but it can be done.

Let's say you have the following markup:

```
<span>Comment</span>
```

Adding a psuedo-element with `:after` will produce something like *"CommentSign the Guestbook"*:

```
span:after { content: "Sign the Guestbook"; }
```

Then you can hide the actual text and reposition the replacement text:

```
span {
  display:inline-block;
  text-indent:-9999px;
}
span:after {
  content: "Sign the Guestbook";
  margin-left:9999px;
}
```

It's not perfect, and it's better to just change the actual text. Replace `span` with the element that has the text, and reduce the `margin-left` by the amount you suspect the original text takes up. You could also use a background image with the desired text, but that's kind of a pain and harder to edit.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zjrSj/1/

Comment: Okay nice, I understand what you're saying, but how do I find the element that has the text?  I apologize for my primitive coding experience and thank you for bearing with me while I learn.

Comment: First off, get [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or hit F12 and get familiar with the developer tools  (assuming you are or intend to be a web developer, it is invaluable to use proper tools), or just look at the source code. Anyways, try `.sqs-comments {}` as a selector (although perhaps you'll need something more specific).

Comment: Okay this works!  But as soon as I click on it and refresh the page, it changes back to the old version.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay but now the problem is, once you click this, the comment box pops up, it says "Post the comment"  would this be solved with the same thing?

Comment: I've tried the same thing, and it displays the new text but it doesn't get rid of the old.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open up your HTML/PHP file and change it to Sign the Guestbook. You can't do it in CSS unless you do some bizarre thing. If this doesn't help you, then please post your code so I can manually help you.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'm using a SS template and don't have a developer account, which is my main problem I think. But here is the link to the blog itself: daniel-nesfeder-yjen.squarespace.com/obituaries

Comment: You can see the reason I need to change the wording is because a "comment" wouldn't be respectful for an obituary, which is my use for the blog feature.